# php decoder function not working?

Tags: php, base64, decode

I have some data in raw email format with base64 encoding, but when I put that encoding into a string variable, and then pass it to the `echo base64_decode($str)` function, it prints out the above.

[image]

Here is a snippet of my code. I didn't post the entire base64 encoding string for obvious reasons.

```
$str = "JVBERi0xLjcKJeTjz9IKNCAwIG9iago8PC9MZW5ndGggMyAwIFIvRmlsdGVy
L0ZsYXRlRGVjb2RlPj4Kc3RyZWFtCnicvVndb9s2ECdgYB28AlnQFGv6ARhY
mg8gVUXxQ1K3vQyO46YGHDt23Dbe07YOGJqH5nF//X53pGXJllzZ8QbZEilK
d7873h2PJ9kKcbySOMVp1Pr9thkGkUILFx1LvijZuvur+aUp+VnZ0iH98Oiv";

echo base64_decode($str);
```

Comment: "not working" You gotta set the correct `Content-Type` header.

Comment: It looks like the base64 is encoding a PDF file. PDF isn't plain text, so you're not going to get anything intelligible by echoing it.